# Adding frame number # of ## on footer lines in Feather theme

Tags: beamer

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[]{Feather}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\newcommand{\chref}[2]{
  \href{#1}{{\usebeamercolor[bg]{Feather}#2}}}

\title[The title] {\textbf{The extended title}}

\author[Name]{Name \\
      {\small Afilliation\\ Company}}

\institute[Institute]{Institute\\}

\date{ }

\begin{document}

{\1
\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Content}{}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\section{Installation}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Source files}
\begin{frame}{Installation}{Source files}
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{}
The theme contains 4 source files:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item {\tt beamercolorthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerouterthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerinnerthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerthemeFeather.sty}
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{User Interface}{Loading the Theme and Theme Options}

  \begin{block}{The Color Theme}
    Also you can load only the color theme by writing in the preamble of the {\tt tex} file

    \vspace{5pt}

    \begin{itemize}
    \item {\tt \textbackslash usecolortheme\{Feather\}}
    \end{itemize}

    \vspace{5pt}

    ...or to change the colors of the various elements in the theme

    \vspace{5pt}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Change the bar colors: \\
    {\tt \textbackslash setbeamercolor \{Feather\}\{fg=<color>, bg=<color>\}}

    \vspace{2pt}

    \item Change the color of the structural elements: \\
    {\tt \textbackslash setbeamercolor\{structure\}\{fg=<color>\}}

    \vspace{2pt}

    \item Change the frame title text color:\\
    {\tt \textbackslash setbeamercolor\{frametitle\}\{fg=<color>\}}

    \vspace{2pt}

    \item Change the normal text color background:
    {\tt \textbackslash setbeamercolor\{normal text\}\{fg=<color>, bg=<color>\}}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}


%-------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Feather image}
\begin{frame}{User Interface}{The Feather Background Image}
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{The Feather Background Image}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item In Feather theme, the title page frame and the last frame have the Feather image as the background image.
    \item The Feather background image can be produced to any frame by writting on the begining at the chosen frame the following
    \end{itemize}

    \vspace{5pt}

  {\tt \{\textbackslash 1bg\\
    \textbackslash begin\{frame\}[<options>]\{Frame Title\}\{Frame Subtitle\}\\
    \ldots\\
    \textbackslash end\{frame\}\}}
\end{block}
\end{frame}


{\1
\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]
  \finalpage{Thank you for using Feather Beamer Theme!}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

A frame from the output is:

[image].

How can I add the frame number #/## (e.g. 3 of 12) at the right of each footer line, except for the first and last page (like in Boadilla theme: [image]) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Feather}

\title{The Feather Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{v. 1.0.0}
\author{Lilyana Vankova}
\institute{Faculty of Mathematics, Informatics and Information}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]%
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=structure.fg,fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.0\paperwidth]{footline}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{3.5ex}%
    \insertshortauthor\ |\ 
    \insertshorttitle
    \insertshortsubtitle \hfill \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```